# How to setup jenkins git url for single project from repository

Tags: android, jenkins, bitbucket

I am working on jenkins android setup,my bitbucket repository contains libraries and android project.I want to generate apk for that android project using jenkins for that i need to serve git url but if i take clone it contains all projects.So how can i take only android project git url to setup in jenkins

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` always pulls the entire repository. If you only need certain parts then you'll either need to split the repo into smaller things or to clone the whole thing and then strip out the unnecessary things.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the GIT Plugin in jenkins. Then configure your newly created Job, in SCM, click Git and paste the URL there. Also, Create a new repo if you want just the smaller part of to get the android files in jenkins. To generate apk in jenkins job, Invoke gradle script in buid trigger then in tasks add `packageDebug`.